# Transfer of astronauts from CSM to LM

Tags: docking, apollo-11, mechanisms

Did the astronauts "remove" the docking probe, the drogue of the LM, and related mechanisms from the CSM to enter the LM of Apollo 11?

Answer (score 9):

After docking both the probe and the drogue were removed, extracted from the tunnel and stored somewhere. [Here](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/09day3-entering-eagle.html) is the transcript from Apollo 11. Some excerpts:

> 055:19:49 Duke: Apollo 11, Houston. It's a pretty good show here. It looks like you almost got the probe out.
>
> 055:19:54 Collins: Yeah, it's loose now.
>
> [...]
>
> 055:22:14 Duke: We can see the probe now. Correction, the drogue.
>
> 055:22:22 Armstrong: Roger. [Long pause.]
>
> 055:23:04 Armstrong: Okay. Drogue removal's coming next.
>
> [...]
>
> 055:24:07 Duke: 11, Houston. Now it's a good view of the storage area under the couch. [Long pause.]

The pictures AS11-36-5382, 5383, and 5384 were taken shortly thereafter showing them both in the LM. As mentioned in the transcript they were stitched together by  Jon Hancock to this:

[image: probe and drogue]

Comment: A brief description of the process, and some photos, can be found here: http://heroicrelics.org/stafford/apollo-probe-and-drogue/

Comment: @ Davin Gremlin. Thanks a lot Davin, I appreciate your feedback. I have seen these photos and read the article, how ever I could not understand CSM and LM mating - "while pulling out the LM from adopter, while separation of LM from CSM while entering lunar orbit, and while reuniting for home coming. I am wondering if the "Drogue" and the "Probe" assemblies in respective vehicles were hinged to their vehicle body, or they had been completely removed. Will try to see Apollo 13 movie clip as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: The components were completely removeable, as pictured in the answer post